# Django rest framework displaying specific field of a model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                  null=True, blank=False, related_name="manager")
```

in my serializers.py

```
class RestaurantSerializer(CoreHyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
```

in my views.py

```
class RestaurantViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.order_by('id').all()
    serializer_class = RestaurantSerializer
```

on my list:

the manager is displaying as `<rest_framework.relations.PKOnlyObject object at 0x9f7040xbc208>`

How can I display it as normal data like its username?

Comment: why don't you have fields on your serializer method?

Comment: because it is a model serializer, it picks up django model fields

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a ['SlugRelatedField'](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).

Comment: How will you implement it with SlugRelatedField?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can go, but if you just want to show a username, all you need is this

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manager = serializers.CharField(source="manager.username")

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
```

if you inherit from ModelSerializer and skip the manager field, it will use user PK as the value of the manager field by default.

a slightly more involved way would be to define a separate serializer for User and then embed it in RestaurantSerializer.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manager = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
```

And if you really want to use hyperlinked serializer, you need to do quite a bit of work. You need to read this part carefully http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined

Comment: This is somewhat right, although the `manager` is being displayed as `Charfield` too in Update view, which should be a Select field of users. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can make two separate definitions of manager field, one read-only and one write-only.